# VBA Excel capture data from count down timer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm Looking to setup a VBA which will capture data 5 mins before the clock stops I have the count down timer in Excel working but I'm clueless to know how to capture data in cell G9 so it is permanently displayed in L9

I have attacthed a picture any help would be great cheers

Comment: Not seeing a picture.  While you are at adding the photo add the code as is at this point also.

Comment: post your code, please

Comment: i dont have any code at the minute i have been trying to use aplication ontime but i cant get it to work with the countdown timer which is imported from a server

Comment: i have used a simple formula so it shows up the data but a soon as the clock moves it disappears again if theres a way of freezing or capturing that data with another formula that would be cool to

Comment: Sub ifs()

If Cells(4, 6) = Cells(4, 8) Then


     Cells(1, 7) = Cells(9, 7)
     
     
     
     
End If


End Sub

Comment: Very simple but because the countdown timer changes the information disapears how do i get it so its capture the data and is static

Comment: Is the countdown timer displaying values in a specific cell?

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a little hard to understand but I think I got what you meant.

Try setting a `Private Sub` to run when there is a change to a cell (in this case, the cell in which the timer is running). Then, just change the `"__"` to the address of the cell of the timer.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "__" Then
    'The code you posted in a comment here
    If Cells(4, 6).Value = Cells(4, 8).Value Then
        Cells(1, 7).Value = Cells(9, 7).Value
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Post your code and the images, you have to make it easy as you can for us to understand what the problem is. Let me know if that works.